# Magento Update and Clean Shoping Cart using Ajax

Tags: ajax, magento, cart

i two days a trying to make this done, but unsuccessful.
i have code on server:

```
<?php               
require_once  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/Mage.php';              
Mage::app();                
mage::log('-----');             
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);                
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();                
foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $quote_item) {             
$quote_item->setQty(55);                
}               
$quote->save();             
mage:log($quote_item);              
$session= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');               
foreach($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item)               
{               
   $productid = $item->getProductId();              
   $productsku = $item->getSku();               
   $productname = $item->getName();             
   $productqty = $item->getQty();               
}               
mage::log('Product: '.$productname.' Qty: '.$productqty);               
mage::log('-----');             
?>
```

i have ajax request:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function updateCart(productId, qty) {
    qty = jQuery('#prodqty').val()
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "HTML",
        data: { productId : productId, qty : qty },
        url: "updateCart.php?productId=" + productId + "&qty=" + qty,
        success: function (data) {
             // alert("Success");
           },
    error: function(data){
                alert("Failure");
             }
         });
     }
 </script>
```

and .phtml file:

```
 <select id='prodqty' onchange="updateCart(20)">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>                
    </select>
```

setQty(55) - this is the desired qty for testing
when i choose option via select, cart update completed fine and log say that all done well. but when i press F5 cart qty same (NOT UPDATED)

for checking situation, i'm move whole .php code (from server) TO magento template (in our case cart.php) I was very surprised when i press F5 and cart has QTY55 (as it is desired for me)

Question - What I missed??? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should add these lines:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

either instead of after `$quote->save();` (not exactly sure about this one)

Comment: @user3558834  damn...I thought it would. here is an other tip. Try to replicate what happens in `Mage_Checkout_CartController::_updateShoppingCart()`. That is the method that updates the qtys in the normal process.

Comment: please tell me how do this, i'm no so deep in this case now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better for you to make a custom module and  override Mage_Checkout_CartController.

```
<config>

<modules>
... Your module info
</modules>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                  <Company_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Company_Checkout</Company_Checkout>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

There you can do something like this:

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Checkout').DS.'CartController.php';

class Company_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
/*
 * Custom Method
 */
public function updateAjaxAction()
{

... your custom code

$item->setQty($qtyData);
$cart->save();
$this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
...
//Generate the results in json
$salida = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result);
```

Then call it from your phtml using ajax. I suggest you to use Prototype too instead of jQuery for Magento.

Regards!